# Basic generic priority queue using an unsorted list

Tags: c#, collections, priority-queue

I am aware that there are other ways of implementing a priority queue e.g. using a sorted array/list. Would appreciate some comments on my implementation of a basic priority queue supporting three simple operations: `Insert, Min, Max`

```
public class QueueEntry<TKey, TValue> : IComparable<QueueEntry<TKey, TValue>> where TKey : IComparable<TKey>
{
    public QueueEntry(TKey key, TValue value)
    {
        Key = key;
        Value = value;
    }
    public TKey Key { get; }
    public TValue Value { get; }

    public int CompareTo(QueueEntry<TKey, TValue> other)
    {
        if (EqualityComparer<QueueEntry<TKey, TValue>>.Default.Equals(this, other)) return 0;
        if (other == null) throw new ArgumentNullException();
        return Key.CompareTo(other.Key);
    }

    public override string ToString() => $"Key = {Key}, Value = {Value}";

}
public sealed class PriorityQueue<TKey, TValue> where TKey : IComparable<TKey>
{
    private List<QueueEntry<TKey, TValue>> items;
    private TKey minKey;
    private TKey maxKey;
    private int minIndex;
    private int maxIndex;

    public PriorityQueue(int capacity)
    {
        items = new List<QueueEntry<TKey, TValue>>(capacity);
        minKey = default(TKey);
        maxKey = default(TKey);
        minIndex = maxIndex = 0;
    }

    public PriorityQueue() : this(10)
    {
    }

    public void Insert(QueueEntry<TKey, TValue> entry)
    {
        if (entry == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(entry));

        var key = entry.Key;
        if (items.Count == 0) // first item
        {
            minKey = key;
            maxKey = key;
        }
        else if (key.CompareTo(minKey) < 0) // a new min key
        {
            minKey = key;
            minIndex = items.Count; // after the insert there will be one more entry.
        }
        else if (key.CompareTo(maxKey) > 0) // a new max key
        {
            maxKey = key;
            maxIndex = items.Count;
        }
        items.Add(entry);
    }

    public int Count => items.Count;
    public bool IsEmpty => items.Count == 0;

    //Delete the entry with the min key; O(n).
    public void DeleteMin()
    {
        if (IsEmpty) throw new InvalidOperationException("Queue is empty");

        items.Remove(items[minIndex]);
        if (!IsEmpty)
        {
            minIndex = 0;
            for (var i = 1; i < items.Count; i++)
            {
                if (items[i].Key.CompareTo(items[minIndex].Key) < 0)
                    minIndex = i;
            }
            minKey = items[minIndex].Key;
        }
    }

    //Delete the entry with the max key; O(n).
    public void DeleteMax()
    {
        if (IsEmpty) throw new InvalidOperationException("Queue is empty");
        items.Remove(items[maxIndex]);
        if (!IsEmpty)
        {
            maxIndex = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < items.Count; i++)
            {
                if (items[i].Key.CompareTo(items[maxIndex].Key) > 1)
                    maxIndex = i;
            }
            maxKey = items[maxIndex].Key;
        }
    }

    //O(1) to get min and max of the queue!
    public QueueEntry<TKey, TValue> Min => IsEmpty ? null : items[minIndex];

    public QueueEntry<TKey, TValue> Max => IsEmpty ? null : items[maxIndex];
}
```

These are some tests using NUnit3:

```
 [TestFixture]
class PriorityQueueTest
{
    [Test]
    public void EmptyQueue_IsEmpty_ReturnTrue()
    {
        var queue = new PriorityQueue<int, string>();
        Assert.IsTrue(queue.IsEmpty);
    }

    [Test]
    public void AfterInsert_IsEmpty_ReturnFalse()
    {
        var queue = new PriorityQueue<int, string>();
        queue.Insert(new QueueEntry<int, string>(1, "item1"));
        Assert.IsFalse(queue.IsEmpty);
    }

    [Test]
    public void FindMin_Return_CorrectMin()
    {
        var queue = new PriorityQueue<int, string>();
        queue.Insert(new QueueEntry<int, string>(3, "item2"));
        var minItem = new QueueEntry<int, string>(1, "min");
        queue.Insert(minItem);
        queue.Insert(new QueueEntry<int, string>(5, "item3"));
        Assert.AreEqual(minItem, queue.Min);
    }

    [Test]
    public void DeleteMin_Once_Return_CorrectMin()
    {
        var queue = new PriorityQueue<int, string>();
        queue.Insert(new QueueEntry<int, string>(1, "min"));
        var newMin = new QueueEntry<int, string>(3, "item2");
        queue.Insert(newMin);
        queue.Insert(new QueueEntry<int, string>(5, "item3"));
        queue.DeleteMin();
        Assert.AreEqual(newMin, queue.Min);
    }

    [Test]
    public void FindMax_Returns_CorrectMax()
    {
        var queue = new PriorityQueue<int, string>();
        queue.Insert(new QueueEntry<int, string>(1, "min"));
        queue.Insert(new QueueEntry<int, string>(3, "item2"));
        var maxItem = new QueueEntry<int, string>(7, "item4");
        queue.Insert(maxItem);
        queue.Insert(new QueueEntry<int, string>(5, "item3"));
        Assert.AreEqual(maxItem, queue.Max);
    }

    [Test]
    public void DeleteSingleItem_FindMin_ThrowInvalidOperation()
    {
        var queue = new PriorityQueue<int, string>();
        queue.Insert(new QueueEntry<int, string>(1, "min"));
        queue.DeleteMin();
        //QueueEntry<int, string> x;
        //Assert.Throws(typeof(InvalidOperationException), () => x = queue.Min);
        Assert.IsNull(queue.Min);
    }

        [Test]
        public void DeleteSingleItem_FindMax_ThrowInvalidOperation()
        {
            var queue = new PriorityQueue<int, string>();
            queue.Insert(new QueueEntry<int, string>(1, "min"));
            queue.DeleteMax();
            //QueueEntry<int, string> x;
            //Assert.Throws(typeof(InvalidOperationException), () => x = queue.Max);
            Assert.IsNull(queue.Max);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I am aware that there are other ways of implementing a priority queue e.g. using a sorted array/list.

ok, for the sake of the review I'll pretend I know only the `List<>`.

---

## Queue or Stack?

- This should be a `PriorityQueue` so I suggest renaming `TKey` to `TPriority` and the `Key` property to `Priority` as this is what the *key* is, right?
- If you look a the .NET [`Queue<>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.queue(v=vs.110).aspx) it has methods like `Enqueue`, `Dequeue` or `Peek` which most users are familiar with and I find you shouldn't invent new names like `Insert` and `DeleteX` for these operations.
- `Min` and `Max` would better be `First` and `Last` as far as queues are concerned.
- But what is a queue?

  > *a queue* represents a first-in, first-out collection of objects.

  so why does your queue have such methods as `DeleteMax` or `DeleteLast` and `Max` or `PeekMax`. You've mixed a stack with a queue here - this is confusing. It should either be queue or a stack. Not both.

  Try to mimic the original API when possible.

---

## Default values

> ```
> minKey = default(TKey);
> maxKey = default(TKey);
> minIndex = maxIndex = 0;
> ```

This is not necessary as their values are already `default(TKey)` and `0`.

---

## Good things

> ```
> if (IsEmpty) throw new InvalidOperationException("Queue is empty");
> ```

This is rarely seen and just as it should be.

---

> ```
> public PriorityQueue(int capacity)
> {
>     ..
> }
>
> public PriorityQueue() : this(10)
> {
> }
> ```

You use constructor overloading and chaining instead of default values. This is good too. If the `10` was only a constant it would be perfect.

Answer (score 2):

A sorted list/array would work a lot faster, but since you are not interested I will comment on your implementation.

- Proper collections should implement at least `IEnumerable` and if suitable add indexer so you can provide a way of iterating that collection.
- Collections implementing `IEnumerable` have the option to provide collection initializer which internally used the `Add()` method, It must be called **Add**, Insert wont work, so you should rename your method to that and also add additional overload to that which accepts only `TKey` and `TValue` not `QueueEntry<TKey, TValue>` so you can make the intialization shorter.

  Examples:

  ```
  PriorityQueue<int, string> withQueueEntries = new PriorityQueue<int, string>
  {
      new QueueEntry<int, string>(1, "a"),
      new QueueEntry<int, string>(1, "b"),
      new QueueEntry<int, string>(1, "c"),
  };

  PriorityQueue<int, string> withEntries = new PriorityQueue<int, string>
  {
      {1, "a"},
      {1, "b"},
      {1, "c"},
  };
  ```
- Do not omit curly braces.
- If you know the index of the item to be removed you better use `items.RemoveAt(index)` instead of `items.Remove(items[index])` the first one is faster the second one is always O(n) operation.
- I'm not a fan of multiple overloads when you can do it in a single one with optional parameters, but this is up to personal preference I guess.

With all of that your class can look like this:

```
public sealed class PriorityQueue<TKey, TValue> : IEnumerable<QueueEntry<TKey, TValue>>
    where TKey : IComparable<TKey>
{
    public int Count => items.Count;
    public bool IsEmpty => items.Count == 0;

    private readonly List<QueueEntry<TKey, TValue>> items;
    private TKey minKey;
    private TKey maxKey;
    private int minIndex;
    private int maxIndex;

    public PriorityQueue(int capacity)
    {
        items = new List<QueueEntry<TKey, TValue>>(capacity);
        minKey = default(TKey);
        maxKey = default(TKey);
        minIndex = maxIndex = 0;
    }

    public PriorityQueue() : this(10)
    {
    }

    public void Add(QueueEntry<TKey, TValue> entry)
    {
        if (entry == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(entry));
        }

        var key = entry.Key;
        if (items.Count == 0) // first item
        {
            minKey = key;
            maxKey = key;
        }
        else if (key.CompareTo(minKey) < 0) // a new min key
        {
            minKey = key;
            minIndex = items.Count; // after the insert there will be one more entry.
        }
        else if (key.CompareTo(maxKey) > 0) // a new max key
        {
            maxKey = key;
            maxIndex = items.Count;
        }
        items.Add(entry);
    }

    public void Add(TKey entryKey, TValue entryValue)
    {
        if (entryKey == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(entryKey));
        }
        if (entryValue == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(entryValue));
        }
        Add(new QueueEntry<TKey, TValue>(entryKey, entryValue));
    }

    //Delete the entry with the min key; O(n).
    public void DeleteMin()
    {
        if (IsEmpty)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Queue is empty");
        }
        items.RemoveAt(minIndex);
        if (!IsEmpty)
        {
            minIndex = 0;
            for (var i = 1; i < items.Count; i++)
            {
                if (items[i].Key.CompareTo(items[minIndex].Key) < 0)
                {
                    minIndex = i;
                }
            }
            minKey = items[minIndex].Key;
        }
    }

    //Delete the entry with the max key; O(n).
    public void DeleteMax()
    {
        if (IsEmpty)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Queue is empty");
        }
        items.RemoveAt(maxIndex);
        if (!IsEmpty)
        {
            maxIndex = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < items.Count; i++)
            {
                if (items[i].Key.CompareTo(items[maxIndex].Key) > 1)
                {
                    maxIndex = i;
                }
            }
            maxKey = items[maxIndex].Key;
        }
    }

    //O(1) to get min and max of the queue!
    public QueueEntry<TKey, TValue> Min => IsEmpty ? null : items[minIndex];

    public QueueEntry<TKey, TValue> Max => IsEmpty ? null : items[maxIndex];

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }

    public IEnumerator<QueueEntry<TKey, TValue>> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return items.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

I haven't touched your `QueueEntry` class as it's something I would write and be happy about it.